# How to translate Symfony 3 forms?

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony-forms, symfony-3.3

Translating content in twig templates seems easy and straightforward: I run `bin/console translation:update` to populate translation files. The issue is that it seems to ignore forms.

After creating entities, repositories and forms/types, I use `{{ form_row(form.field) }}` in twig templates to draw the form elements.

**Is there a well-established practice on how to customize and translate form labels, placeholders and errors messages?**

Must I use `form_label` and `form_widget` instead of `form_row` to customize labels?

Comment: Don't you use FormTypes? Try to inject Translator into your FormType and Translate the Fields Labels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create for example a file named `forms.es.yml` here, you can put you traductions in spanish, and in your forms you can chain it like this:

```
//LoginType.php
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('email',
            EmailType::class,
            [
                'translation_domain' => 'forms', //It's translate the label
                'constraints' => [
                    new Email([
                        'message' => 'email'
                    ])
                ]
            ]
        )
        ->add('password',
            RepeatedType::class,
            [
                'type' => PasswordType::class,
                'invalid_message' => 'cliente.password_not_equal',
                'first_options' => ['label' => 'cliente.password'],
                'second_options' => ['label' => 'cliente.repeat_password'],
                'translation_domain' => 'forms', //Here is again
                'constraints' => [
                    new NotBlank([
                        'message' => 'not_blank'
                    ])
                ]
            ]
        )
        ->add('current_uri', HiddenType::class);
}
```

It works since symfony 2.

Another way is in your twig, only print the widget and translate the label:

```
//index.html.twig
<label> 
   {{'form.email'|trans({})}}
   {{ form_widget('form.email') }} //It only prints the input tag
</label>
```

Is an easy way, but is less reusable.

Comment: I think the first approach is working well. The only issue I'm facing is: if I run `bin/console translation:update en` it seems to ignore all my forms. Do I need to manually maintain the translation files?

Comment: Sorry but, i think so. If there is a way to do it automatically, I don't know it :c. Actually I'm maintaining it manually.

Comment: Is there any new ways of generating all xliff entries for translation_domain used in FormType? The translation:update command seems to ignore forms still in 2020? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

To translate form errors as explained on documentation https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/translations.html

You need validators.lang_used.format file with key/value par. Then pass the key over Assert validation upon message key.

On Entity

```
// src/Entity/Author.php
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

class Author
{
    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="author.name.not_blank")
     */
    public $name;
}
```

On form creation

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder()
    ->setMethod('GET')
    ->add('email', TextType::class, [
        'constraints' => [
            new NotBlank(['message' => 'error.not_blank']),
        ],
        'label' => 'label.email-domain'
    ])
    ->getForm();
```

To translate Label just pass the keys to 'label', the keys need be prefix with *label* an live on messages.* file.

Translate plain text on view (key/value are defined on messages.* files)

```
{{ 'save_button'|trans }}
```

For examples of translation see https://github.com/symfony/demo look for Entity definition, views file and Form Type

Answer (score 0):

Solution of @Koronos is not bad, but I suggest mine, because in @Koronos solution you have to repeat 'translation_domain' => 'forms' over and over again, on each form input. To get rid of this, here is my solution, in controller or whatever place I init form object (code example of Symfony 6.0.0):

```
<?php

#[Route('/admin/clients/update/{id}', name: 'client_update')]
public function update(Request $request, int $id): Response
{
    $client = $this->clientRepository->find($id);

    $form = $this->createForm(ClientFormType::class, $client, ['translation_domain' => 'forms']);
    
    // do other actions here
}
```

After that, I only need to config label on each form input in form class, describing translation key. This is answer for the year 2023 and for Symfony 6.